# Navigation not showing on-top of my video set as a background

Tags: php, html, css, styles

So on my website, I have a video set as a background, everything I put underneath the video shows, but everything on top won't show.

**index.php**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <body>

<div class="navigation">
      <a href="blog.php">Updates</a>
              <a href="#">|</a>
      <a href="blog.php">Start</a>
              <a href="#">|</a>
      <a href="blog.php">Login</a>
</div>


<video autoplay muted loop id="background_video">
  <source src="assets/backgrounds/index_background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**style.css**

```
 .navigation{
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 z-index: auto;
 float: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: white;
 position: fixed;
 }
 #background_video{
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 50%;
 z-index: 0;
 }
```

Comment: have you tried setting z-index ??

Comment: @Chiller Yes I have, but unfortunately you can't set z-index:-1 xD (or can you?)

Comment: @Chiller Okay, its solved now, turns out you can set z-index into the negatives xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the z-index.
The z-index of the ".navigation" class must be greater/higher than the z-index of the video element with the ID "#background_video".

And you cannot use two "position" in ".navigation" class. The "absolute" is being overwritten by "fixed".